# Bluemix news api transaction limit exceeded

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I have added the Alchemy API service to my Bluemix dashboard and can use the credentials to call the API.  I have configured the service to use the "Ecosystem" plan.

My App calls the news API fine for the first few calls and then I get `API transaction limit exceeded`.  Is there a limit for calls on the Ecosystem plan?

Thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alchemy API is tricky. You're probably reaching the 1000 events a day.

First, you need to understand how the events are count.

Here is an example:

```
To calculate how many transaction credits a query will cost, multiply historical access and targeting.

Historical Access - each hour of historical access costs 1 transaction credit
Targeting - each query parameter costs 1 transaction credit

Example: Give me news about the company "IBM" from the past 3 days.

    Historical access: 3 days = 72 transaction credits
    Targeting: 1 query parameter = 1 transaction credit
    Query cost: 72 transaction credits
```

see https://www.alchemyapi.com/alchemydata-news-sales for more explanation

second, you need to check how many credits you've already used. Use this API for that

http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/info/GetAPIKeyInfo?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

finally, cache everything you retrieve from AlchemyAPI (bluemix has several options for that)

Comment: Hi Leo - thanks for such a quick reply.  I took a look at my API key limits and it looks like the Bluemix ecosystem gives 100,000 transactions a day.  Sounds a lot but it isn't too hard to use 1000 in a single call.  Appreciate the help.  Cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to see more analytics on this? For instance, daily usage for last 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

The two plans currently available for AlchemyAPI service are Free and Standard. The Free Plan includes 1,000 events per day per Bluemix Organization. You can only have one instance at a time of the AlchemyAPI service and one AlchemyAPI credential in the Free plan. If you need to create an additional instance or credential you need to upgrade to the Standard plan.

Take a look at the [Alchemy API Service terms](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/pdf/0012-01/$file/i128-0012-01_09-2015_en_US.pdf) and [AlchemyAPI on Bluemix details](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/alchemyapi).